# Why I cannot have original geometry in PyMesh after meshing?

Tags: pymesh

Sorry it maybe too easy but in PyMesh, when I define a geometry file like this [[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyuGC.png],by using the simplest example code in Tutorial as follow:

```
vertices = nodes # The vertex of polygon
tri = pymesh.triangle()
tri.points = vertices
tri.max_area = 0.05
tri.split_boundary = False
tri.verbosity = 0
tri.run(); # Execute triangle
mesh = tri.mesh; # output triangulation
```

The generated mesh is as follow which has a chamfer, but I want exact geometry.
[[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPNh1.png]
Please help!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friend according to this link https://github.com/PyMesh/PyMesh/issues/95 I should define segments.
So it solved!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).